# Caching by key with defined String variables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

Hello I have a String value which I can import from common constant class

I want to join with a parameter in the method but I could not give as a key :)

For example: I have an String KEY_DELIMETER imported by the class which is equal to "::".

```
@Cacheable(key = "#appId" + KEY_DELIMETER + "userId")
public UserProfile getUserProfile(final String appId, final String appconnectId)
```

I am not able to use key_delimeter as a constant.

Is there a way to use like that?

Comment: can you try @Cacheable(value="bookCache", key = "#appId.append("KEY_DELIMETER").append("userId")")

Comment: It appears that what you're looking for could be done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59029600/422979)